# Python Lists Replacement of Certain Characters through Recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion

I am working through a project which requires a very basic level of Python coding experience. This course I am taking actually forbids basically all advanced tools that may be used to solve many problems. I need assistance on writing a recursive function that takes a list of a completed board game score and paints the correct symbols with the correct symbol for each player. Here is one example provided:

```
++++XO+++ ----> XXXXXOOOO
```

Basically the function replaces the '+' with and 'X' or 'O' depending on which symbol is touching the set of '+'. I already wrote the rest of the file that takes in many of these random sets of scores and stores them as lists. I was mainly stuck on working with lists and replacing the correct '+' and using recursion for the process.

Any help or just an explanation on how this function could be written would be amazing.

*Edit: We use mostly for and while loops, along with if, elif, and else statements. Basically just the basics of Python is allowed.

Comment: What if the "+++" were in the middle between an "O" and an "X"?

Comment: The teacher has told us that is not a concern for this assignment and they will not test that scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"forbids basically all advanced tools"

What tools would be considered too advanced? Would simply writing

```
for element in List:
    if element == something:
```

What are we allowed to use?

Edit:

```
L = "+++OX++++++"
L = list(L)
new_L = []
n = 0
for x in range(len(L)):
    if L[x] != "+":
        n += 1
        if n == 1:
            p = x + 1    #for the first occurrence of a string that is not +, we set p as the index of that character + 1
        else:
            p = len(L) - x    #we look how many more characters are left from the index of the character in the list and set that as p
        new_L += [L[x] for _ in range(p)]    #This is a list comprehension, we add the character p times to the new list, the _ is just a variable we don't need
```

This might not be very readable for beginners though.

Basically, we go over each element, once we find an element which is not "+" we can do the code. If x is the position of the character in L, then we add that character x + 1 times to the new list. When we come across a character for the second time, if x is the position of that character in L, then amount of p is the remaining characters left, so we put that character p times in the new list.

This is not a perfect solution since it only works if the 2 characters are right next to each other, but it's a start.

Comment: Sorry for being too vague, that is perfectly fine code that can we use in the class.

Comment: Thanks so much I was able to finish my project!

Comment: Was that a correct solution though? What if you have a list where the O and X aren't right next to each other?

Comment: The 'lists' that we are changing are part of a game and are just randomly supplied from my teacher and every example must have a 'XO' touching each other, never separated by any symbols. This was my first time using Stack Overflow so thanks so much for the assistance.